# How Can You Reformat an OTU Table from qiime2 pathway to Include Sequence IDs?

Tags: qiime

I am trying to run Tax4Fun in MicrobiomeAnalyst, but am running into trouble with my table formatting. From the qiime2 pathway, I have an OTU, metadata and taxonomic table formatted like so:
[OTU table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pwuZ.png) [metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRcA.png) [taxonomy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlILq.png)

In order to use Tax4Fun, I understand that I will need to reformat my OTU table to include sequence IDs so it looks like this example:
[Sample Sequence OTU table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYdEX.png)

However, I cannot figure out how to merge my sequence files from the qiime2 pathway with the OTU table so it looks like that. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!